# Concurrency: Wait until common block of code is done

Tags: java, concurrency, producer-consumer

I am writing a multi-threaded server, with needs to handle client requests and return them back to the client when done.

I have a list of concurrent client connections object, which pass on payloads to a common queue. After going through the queue, the payloads are handled by the server and responses are generated.

The problem I have is that I have no idea how to notify the client that the server has finished processing.

This is the thread that handles client payloads, payLoad is a BlockingQueue, which was previously loaded by client threads:

```
 Thread messageHandling = new Thread() {
        public void run(){
            while(true){
                try{
                    Object payLoad= payLoads.take();
                    // Do some handling                        
                   // SEND REPLY BACCK TO THE CLIENT
                }
                catch(InterruptedException e){ }
            }
        }
    };
```

At the same time, on the client side, the following is happening:

```
{
   ...
payloads.add(payLoad)
/// Sleep until the server is done doing its logic with the payload
```

}

The commented bits are where I am having trouble. I have no idea how to implements a mechanism where the client thread will wait until the request is processed and, once it is, I do not know how to send the reply back to the client.

I have spent plenty of time researching, looked at the consumer/producer problem, wait/notify mechanism, etc, but nothing seems to be similar to this particular problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *"but nothing seems to be similar to this particular problem."* As per my understanding you have on instance (the server) that keeps the Jobs and collects the results while many Clients pulling available jobs and need to report the results, right?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: OK, then you need 2 methods in your "dispatcher" object, the `take()` method, your code already has and a method to return the results like `report(JobResult jr)`. The clients get their job as you already have. when they finished, they report their result and the "dispatcher" object must match the results with the jobs and do what ever it is supposed to do with the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store client connection information next to payload in your `payloads`.

Create class with two fields. One of them will be your payload and another is something that allow you to identify your client.

In your `// SEND REPLY BACCK TO THE CLIENT` just send response. No need to wait in `/// Sleep until the server is done doing its logic with the payload`

Without knowing which way you communicate with client I can't give you better answer.

In case you use sockets "something that allow you to identify your client" will be socket instance.

**Other approach** will be using `SynchronousQueue`.

In `// SEND REPLY BACCK TO THE CLIENT` you put your response in it.

In `/// Sleep until the server is done doing its logic with the payload` you take response (method will block until response is putted in buffer).

Pass buffer with payload same way as in previous approach.

Comment: Thank you, this does make sense. So in this case, I should not have a waiting part in the client thread and the socket should be written to and closed from the server method once its work is done?

Comment: Yes. First approach is better because it doesn't block reading thread.